# Checking if an item is in an object

Tags: javascript, object

I am currently doing a problem called Two Sum https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/ , and I want to check if an item is in a set. I wrote the following code:

```
function twoSum(arr, target) {
  const hash = {};
  const res = [];

  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    const num = arr[i]; 
    const diff = target - num; 

    if(diff in hash) {
      res.push(hash[diff], i);
      return res;
    }
    hash[num] = i;
  }

  return [];
  
}

twoSum([3,3], 6) // [0,1]
```

Specifically this check here:

```
if(diff in hash)
```

I was wondering if I can change that to:

```
if(hash[diff])
```

I thought that would make sense, because I believe this check will return `true` since the reverse here would check if the diff is not already in a set:

```
if(!hash[diff])
```

So why is that not working as I expected?

Comment: `if(hash[diff])` will check if `hash[diff]` is _truthy_ which will be true for every value _except_ the 0th index since `0` is falsey

Comment: I might recommend looking into the `Set` object for a more idiomatic way to store whether a number has been seen.

Answer (score 0):

`diff in hash` checks if `diff` is a *property* of the object.

`diff[hash]` checks if the *value* at `diff` is truthy or not.

Because your `i` starts at 0, and that's the value you put on the object:

```
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
```

```
hash[num] = i;
```

the `i` will be falsey on the first iteration, so it won't pass the test.

You could make it work with

```
if(hash[diff] !== undefined)
```

if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit unclear on this: for the first iteration, the `diff` isn't going to be on the `hash` regardless of how you check it, so falsey is expected. However, for the second iteration, the code went inside `if(diff in hash) {` but not `if(hash[diff])`. Why is that?

Comment: Because `hash[diff]` results in `hash[3]`, and `hash[3]` was assigned `undefined`, due to the last line of the prior iteration: `hash[num] = i;` was `hash[3] = 0;`. And 0 is falsey. `if (0)` is not fulfilled, but the `in` resolves to `true`, so `if (true)` does get fulfilled.